# How to not load all database records in my TListbox in Firemonkey Delphi XE8

Tags: database, delphi, device, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a multi device project in Delphi Xe8. I have a TListBox component that i load with database records.

The problem is that sometimes the list can be really big and so the loading will take long. So I want to load it partially and when I scroll down load new records. How do I do that?

Right now i load every record of my table using a TFDQuery.

**Update:**
After some timing I have realized that the problem doesn't lay with loading all the records from the database, but rather with creating all the TListBoxItems in the TListBox. So I still want to do pretty much the same, but now load all the database records but not create TListBoxItems for all of them.

Comment: Can you add conditions or "top" to your query so the query will not return all the records in your table?

Comment: @Tim3880 Well it's a SQLite database so you can do simple queries

Answer (score 2):

From the Embarcadero wiki on [TFDQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery_Properties) you can set the [BlockReadSize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.BlockReadSize)

> For BDE-enabled datasets, setting BlockReadSize also causes the
>   dataset to fetch database information in blocks of BlockReadSize
>   records, which it then buffers. This minimizes traffic between your
>   application and the database server.

Another thing you can try are the [FetchOptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions) of the TFDQuery which have [RowSetSize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.RowsetSize) property

I don't have at the moment FireMonkey so I can test this.

Comment: I will! I've tried to use the RowSetSize property with my TFDQuery but that doesn't do it sadly. But also if you read my update you can see that I now don't need to load the database partially but instead don't load all the ListBoxItems